# How dangerous is Naphtha?

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety

According to a [safety datasheet of Naphtha](https://download.basf.com/p1/000000000030052956_SDS_GEN_US/en_US/Naphtha_000000000030052956_SDS_GEN_US_en_2-0.pdf), it's fairly dangerous stuff (including genetic defects). But, as they say, the dose makes the poison, just how much dose should I be worried about?

Currently, we use a silicone adhesion primer ([SP-270](https://nusil.avantorsciences.com/assetsvc/asset/en_US/id/29204353/contents/en_us_sds_nusisp-270.pdf)), which is dissolved in Naphtha. We use it in a fume cupboard, brushing it onto small metal parts with a tiny brush. The Naphtha evaporates pretty quickly, before we remove the metal part from the fume cupboard. We don't wear gloves.

**Questions:**

- Does this method of handling Naphtha sound unsafe?
- How much exposure to Naphtha is necessary before I'm likely to experience any of the nasty effects? If I accidentally touch the brush, should I be worried? Or do I need to swim in it to get an effect?

**Added clarification:**

The datasheet does not discuss the level of exposure required to cause the listed effects. For example, the [safety datasheet for Paracetamol](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/GB/en/sds/sial/p0300000) says "Harmful if swallowed", but doesn't say how much you need to swallow before it's harmful. Adults can actually swallow up to 4g of it per day, but 24g is fatal. Perhaps there's something similar that can be said about Naphtha?

Comment: For the person downvoting: please can you explain how I can improve this question? Why is it worse than some of the other questions asking about the dangers of certain substances?

Comment: To put the risks of naphtha in perspective, the ingredients are fairly similar to the composition of the petrol (gasoline) you use in large quantities to power cars. The short term risks are its flammability in large quantities; the long term risks arise from repeated exposure to large amounts. The long terms risks involve regular repeated exposure which you can minimise with gloves and ventilation.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Read the question. I literally cite and link to the datasheet in the question. My question involves what's *not* mentioned in the datasheet. Perhaps I can explain it another way: The SDS for Paracetamol says "Harmful if swallowed". And yet adults can actually swallow up to 4g of it per day, but 24g is fatal. Perhaps there's something similar that can be said about Naphtha?

Comment: Naphtha and gasoline are synonymous enough that a report on the carcinogenicity of gasoline should be a good surrogate for one on naphtha. Et voici: https://cfpub.epa.gov/ncea/risk/recordisplay.cfm?deid=36176 [U.S. EPA. Evaluation of the Carcinogenicity of Unleaded Gasoline. U.S. Environmental Protection Agency, Washington, D.C., EPA/600/6-87/001 (NTIS PB87186151).]

Comment: This is a basic chemical safety and practice question not a personal medical question. it should be reopened.

Comment: On the practical side, if you are handling the substances in a fume hood (cupboard), wearing proper gloves, and out of precaution protective eyeware and a labcoat, you should be ok. More generally, somebody might respond by posting the dose response curve.

Comment: eg https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24179027/